# How to check if a field value exists before inserting in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I have a working ELK with input coming from filebeat prospecting several log files and sending them to logstash. Logstash retrieves the stream, filters that in order to match lines with some fields and then sends them into elasticsearch.
Now I would like to check before output to elasticsearch, if for a coming entry into elasticsearch, there is already an existing document. If yes, I want to apply another output plugin instead of elasticsearch.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elasticsearch.html